# find every 5th record from table

Tags: sql, sybase

There are n record in a table `ABC` . 
write  a query to select every 5th record from the table.

for example there are 30 rows in a table.
so query should output 5th,10th,15th,20th, 25th and 30th record from the table.

I tried `ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY id )` but getting msg :-

Message from SQL server IML (msg 156, level 15, state 2):

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'.

I am using Sybase database.

Comment: How would you determine which row is the 5th?

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` doesn't work on SYBASE!

Comment: @Parado : how can I solve the problem :(

Comment: @avinashse I added the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define order to get every 5th row. It can be for example PRIMARY KEY ID or something like this

```
select * from
(
  select ABC.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as RN from ABC
) t1
where RN % 5 = 0
```

Comment: I've changed the query. Try it now.

Comment: showing agani `Message from SQL server IML (msg 156, level 15, state 2):
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'.
` error

Comment: Make sure [ROW_NUMBER() OVER](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1520/html/iqrefbb/iqrefbb262.htm) goes with brackets. It is a function.

Comment: I am querying :- 
`select * from (select test_sal.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) as RN from test_sal) where RN % 5 = 0;
`

getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

This is not how SQL works.  I'm not sure which column would give you what you want, but you aren't supposed to know or care about how the data is stored or what the ordering might be.

You need to figure out a WHERE clause that gives you what you want.  Something depending on order is wrong.

Comment: If sypace dan calculate a row number (which most sql can) you can use that to filter (%5) in a select on the previous query. Stnadard for example for paging etc. See answer by valex.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  select rn, col_list from (select rownum rn, col_list from tab_name)
  where rn=N;
```

where N is the row number you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

Create temporary table with identity column.

```
select 
id = identity(8),
column1,....
into #ABC
from ABC
```

Select with modulo:

```
select * from #ABC
where  id % 5 = 0
```